# Disable Right Click in website

Tags: javascript, right-click, disabled-control

I have this code below to disable right click. When you hit the right click it says Function is disabled. which works but i want it to show nothing at all basicaly when you hit the right click nothing happens... what kind of magic can we use to do that?

```
var message="Function Disabled!"; function clickIE4(){ 
if (event.button==2){ alert(message); return false; } } 
function clickNS4(e){ 
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){ 
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){ alert(message); return false; } } } 
if (document.layers){ document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); document.onmousedown=clickNS4; } 
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){ document.onmousedown=clickIE4; } document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
```

Comment: java is to javascript as car is to carpet

Comment: You realize people can just turn off JS and right click all they want, right? Or load up developer tools and disable your event handler?  This would basically be just a minor nuisance.

Comment: Just remove alert(message) on your code you are done :)

Comment: yes they can but at least it would prevent majority of people stealing.... I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the alert:

```
if (event.button==2){ return false; } }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
## How To Disable Right Click with Out Display any thing or Var Massage  ##
<script language=JavaScript>
<!--
var message="";
function clickIE4()
function clickNS4(e){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}
}

if (document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")

// --> 
</script>
```

Comment: This is wrong, bad practise ("script language=JavaScript"), code-only and does not even (!) answer the question. Grammar is wrong too.

Comment: Hi Leo Lam you I don't think so to tell the KG'S put in the <body> and the above code </body> just try it in any html and feel the difference

Comment: Have you really tested it or read the question? Your code still has an `alert()` call in it. Read the question and your code again.