# disable right click in javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, mouseevent

When I was trying to disable the right click, it is not working.
I tried with below code.

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log(e.button);
  if(e.button == 2){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Based on below link only I tried.
[Disable Right Click in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657866/disable-right-click-in-website)

I tested this code in Chrome and Firefox.
Every time I am getting the right output only in console. I mean "0" for left click and "2" for right click.But still the default action is happening. May I know the reason.?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using wrong event. For right click you should use `oncontextmenu`. You used `onclick` which obviously don't fire in right click and hence the loop doesn't evaluate to true in this case.

```
document.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
    console.log(e.button);
    if (e.button == 2) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/748/

Answer (score 0):

Only three lines of code can disable right click on a web page that is given below:

```
$("html").on("contextmenu",function(e){
   return false;
});
```

Source: [**Close current tab in browser window using JavaScript**](https://www.codespeedy.com/disable-right-click-copy-cut-on-web-page-using-jquery/)